# Calling the default constructor

Tags: c++

This program gives the correct output, but I can't understand how. How is the default constructor called at the time of the declaration of the object?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GuessMe {
private:   
    int *p;
public:
    GuessMe(int x=0) 
    {
        p = new int;
    }
    int GetX() 
    {
        return *p;
    }
    void SetX(int x) 
     {
        *p = x;
     }
    ~GuessMe() 
     {
        delete p;
     }
};

 int main() {
    GuessMe g1;
    g1.SetX(10);
    GuessMe g2(g1);
    cout << g2.GetX() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right.Code is wrong. You have to make the default constructor explicitly there.

Comment: but it gives the correct output

Comment: Are you asking why you can create object `g1` without specifying any parameters for the constructor of `GuessMe` as in `GuessMe g1;`? If yes, then that has to do with the default argument that is assigned to `x` in case you do not specify a parameter yourself

Comment: @TalhaIrfan, A default constructor is one that can be called with no arguments, so it already exists.

Comment: read up on default arguments: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/

Comment: Note that the code has undefined behaviour. `p` is deleted twice. Here's an [example run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/392ffe5dbfcec8c3).

Answer (score 5):

This constructor has a default parameter:

```
GuessMe(int x=0)
```

That means that when a `GuessMe` is default constructed, it is as if it had been called with an argument with value `0`. Note that the constructor parameter isn't used for anything in your code. Also note that `p` is set to point to an uninitialized integer here:

```
p = new int;
```

so calling `GetX()` before calling `SetX()` would yield *undefined behaviour*. Presumable you want to use the value of `x` to set `p`:

```
GuessMe(int x=0) 
{
    p = new int(x);
}
```

or, using initialization instead of assignment,

```
GuessMe(int x=0) : p(new int(x))
{
}
```

Also, read up on [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) to avoid double-deletes. And then learn to code without raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects.